# SQL optimizing query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that has the following records:

```
    ID | Username | Selected |
   ----------------------------
    1  |  JamesC  |     1    |
    2  |  MikeF   |     0    |
    3  |  JamesC  |     0    |
```

I wish to have Selected be true for only 1 row where the username is the same. So for example when I set `ID = 3` to be `Selected = true` I wish to set`ID =1` to have `Selected = false` as well as any other ID's with the same username.

Right now i'm doing this,

```
//set all to 0
update table set selected = 0 where username = '$username'

//set unique row to true
update table set selected = 1 where username = '$username' and ID = '$ID';
```

Is there a better more concise way of achieving the same effect?

Comment: What SQL Database are you using? Please tag with that.

Comment: @shiva sorry am using MySql

Comment: Another table with selected whatever they ares?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it was said - not very nice db structure, it is better to have table with unique names and ID of selected item, anyway, you can go with this single query:

```
update table set selected=IF(id = '$ID', 1, 0) where username = '$username';
```

also, try a possible faster variant (test both via explain):

```
update table set selected=IF(id <> '$ID', 0, 1) where username = '$username';
```

Comment: Can you explain why this structure is not optimal? Yes it's not BCNF but is that better then doing a join to find selected values for every row?

Comment: @Edward what joins? just table with user names and for each user name only one int field with selectedId, so you will be able just to use `update table set selected=$ID where username=$username`

Answer (score 1):

It looks more like optimizing db structure to me. More info needed for concrete answer though, but check this example to see what I'm talking about:

users:

```
user_id | user_name | selected_character_id | ...other account data
1       | JamesC    | 3
2       | MikeF     | 2
```

characters:

```
character_id | user_id | ...other character data
1            | 1       |
2            | 2       |
3            | 1       |
```

You will need `JOIN` tables to retrieve all data for selected character (fast since it operates on unique ids), but get rid of data duplication (and easier switch).

Answer (score 0):

You will always need the second statement, but as you only have one "Selected" row you could use:

```
update table set selected = 0 where selected = 1
```

Comment: OP is asking *"true for only 1 row where the username is the same"*, it this the answer for OP? then could you explain for OP and me?

Comment: You are right, missed the "where username is the same".

It also seems to me the OP falls into the [X/Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)...